# Process not running properly when started from a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I have a dll compiled in C# that executes an external process (wkhtmltoimage) in addition to performing a number of other functions.  Under normal use conditions, there are no problems.  The process starts, standard in/out are both redirected properly, and I get the output I am expecting to see.  However, the particular function in this dll that executes wkhtmltoimage can also be called from a thread other than the main thread in which case, the process hangs.  The input is identical, stdin appears to be working when I watch the memory usage of the spawned process itself, but I have no way to check stdout or stderr since the process never finishes.  I have looked to see if there are any nuances of executing a process from a thread, but I haven't seen anything that would indicate there are any problems.  There are no dead locks as I have been testing with only a single thread, and tracing through the code stops waiting for the process to finish.  The process itself uses about half of the memory I would expect when it executes properly (about 15MB), so I don't know if there is a limit on the thread memory that this spawned process is being lumped into?

Any ideas would be very helpful.  I have tried a number of things to get it working, to no avail...

```
Process p = new Process();
StreamWriter stdin;

p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(this.imageConvertBinPath, "wkhtmltoimage.exe");
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("--debug-javascript --stop-slow-scripts --window-status complete --crop-h {0} --crop-w {1} - \"{2}\"", this.Height, this.Width, imgFilePath);

p.Start();

stdin = p.StandardInput;
stdin.AutoFlush = true;
stdin.Write(testHTML);
stdin.Close();
p.WaitForExit(15000);
```

This code works fine in a non-threaded environment, but hangs on p.WaitForExit before eventually being killed below in a threaded environment.  This is running a single thread (for testing), and is not a processor or memory intensive process.

The input passed through stdin is identical in both cases, and I have even tested with extremely trivial "hello world" input.

Comment: `p.WaitForExit(15000);` remove the number from inside the `p.WaitForExit()` and try it that way also when you are finished with the StreamWriter object you need to dispose / set it to null.. also you need this last line added as well `proc.Close();` as your last line

Comment: this is looks like very DLL implementation specific. Look on the code, if you can (using say dotPick, if the code is not available to you and DLL is not obfuscated) of DLL, and see if the method you are calling is written in a way to handle a call from another thread.

Comment: @MethodMan `.Close` method is enough for disposing the `StreamWriter`

Comment: I am a bit closer to figuring out what is going on, but not closer at the same time.  When the process is started from my .NET app running under IIS, it works fine.  However, when I start the process from a standalone binary calling the same dll, it fails.  I figured out why it is stopping at least. The javascript is failing at a window[className] lookup only when the process is started from the standalone app. The page renders fine in all browsers as well with no errors. I suspect maybe a problem with how it is being passed through stdin? Is there a buffer size limit for a StreamWriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is now fixed. I am passing fusioncharts javascript through stdin to wkhtmltoimage, and there are apparently 3 characters in the fusioncharts.js file that are unicode and not readable by wkhtmltoimage when running as a standalone application. The strange thing is, when I run this exact same program as a service, or execute wkhtmltoimage through the main .NET app under IIS, it works fine. Not sure why it worked in one context (running as a service) and not in another (running as a standalone app), but it is now working.